# Property of multiplication in (Banach) algebra $\ell^{1}(\mathbb{Z})$.

Tags: ring-theory, proof-writing, alternative-proof, convolution, banach-algebras

Consider the Banach algebra $\ell^{1}(\mathbb{Z})$ with multiplication $$(x\ast y)_{k}:=\sum_{l\in\mathbb{Z}}x_{k-l}y_{l}.$$ This may seem strange, but I know how to solve the following problem. I'm just looking for a neat short argument because I think that should be possible. Here is the problem:

> If $e_{n}$ denotes the standard $n$-th coordinate sequence, then $e_{n}=e_{1}^{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

I only know a way to prove it by distinguishing some cases and it bothers me because I think the argument can be really short. So I was wondering if there was a more straightforward way (maybe a one-line proof).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Show that $e_n*e_m=e_{n+m}$.  The result then follows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So from this I conclude that $e_{n}=e_{1}\ast\ldots\ast e_{1}$ ($n$ times $e_{1}$) for positive $n$. What about $n\leq 0$?

Comment: This shows that $e_n^{-1}=e_{-n}$.